# reading dates from xls to csv through Perl

Tags: string, excel, perl, date, csv

I have a batch of excel files with lines like

```
1/13/04 21
```

I am trying to convert them to .csv, but find that the line is converted to

```
36537,21
```

It turns out this is a side-effect of excel's storage rules. Excel should store dates as days since Jan 1, 1900. By that rule, this is the wrong integer, corresponding to Jan 12, 2001 not Jan 13, 2004 (which is the date meant by `1/13/04`).

- How on earth could Excel make that mistake?
- And how can I get the raw unformatted value, sidestepping the conversion in effect here?

This is a rough sketch of the code:

```
my $xlsparser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $xlsbook = $xlsparser->Parse('xls_test.xls');
my $xls = $xlsbook->{Worksheet}[0];
my $csv = '';

# then a loop over rows and columns with...
  my $cell = $xls->get_cell( $row, $col );
  $cellcon = $cell->unformatted();
  $csv .= $cellcon;
```

In case my exposition isn't clear enough or you can't reproduce the issue, here is a minimal data set and script that reproduce it for me:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58760/softwareGrr/xls_example.pl
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58760/softwareGrr/junk.xls

Comment: I can't reproduce.  `01/13/04` gets converted to `37999` in Excel for me.  What version are you using?

Comment: For what I'm doing, I shouldn't need to use Excel; everything is in Perl (version 5.16.3, Win x64, with version 0.65 of the `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` package). The file I'm looking at is in Excel 97-2003 format according to its metadata. I'll see if I can excerpt a date from the (confidential) file and see the same result (in which case, I'll put it on Dropbox).

Comment: @Degustaf I have added a link to files that reproduce the issue on my computer.

Comment: `perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -Mstrict -wE 'my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("1900 1 1", "%Y %m %d"); $t = $t->add(ONE_DAY) for 1 .. 36537; say $t'` returns `Fri Jan 14 00:00:00 2000`.

Comment: @choroba Okay, so it's Jan 14 2000 not Jan 12 2001. Blame the site I used to check that value. Is your comment meant to be enlightening beyond that? I still don't see a correspondence between Jan 14 2000 and the original value of "1/13/04". As an update: I just tried the files above on my home computer and found the same result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert the Excel date serial value format 36537,21 to a time/date variables in perl, then you can use your own functions to convert the dates.
Below the functions

```js
sub date2excelvalue {
  my($day1, $month, $year, $hour, $min, $sec) = @_;
  my @cumul_d_in_m = (0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365);
  my $doy = $cumul_d_in_m[$month - 1] + $day1;

  #
  full years + your day
  for my $y(1900..$year) {
    if ($y == $year) {
      if ($month <= 2) {

        #
        dont add manually extra date
        if inJanuary or February
        last;
      }
      if ((($y % 4 == 0) && ($y % 100 != 0)) || ($y % 400 == 0) || ($y == 1900)) {
        $doy++;#
        leap year
      }
    } else {#
      full years
      $doy += 365;
      if ((($y % 4 == 0) && ($y % 100 != 0)) || ($y % 400 == 0) || ($y == 1900)) {
        $doy++;#
        leap year
      }

    }
  }#
  end
  for y# calculate second parts as a fraction of 86400 seconds
  my $excel_decimaltimepart = 0;
  my $total_seconds_from_time = ($hour * 60 * 60 + $min * 60 + $sec);
  if ($total_seconds_from_time == 86400) {
    $doy++;#
    just add a day
  } else {#
    add decimal in excel
    $excel_decimaltimepart = $total_seconds_from_time / (86400);
    $excel_decimaltimepart = ~s / 0\. //;
  }
  return "$doy\.$excel_decimaltimepart";

}

sub excelvalue2date {
  my($excelvalueintegerpart, $excelvaluedecimalpart) = @_;
  my @cumul_d_in_m = (0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365);
  my @cumul_d_in_m_leap = (0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366);
  my @cumul_d_in_m_selected;
  my($day1, $month, $year, $hour, $min, $sec);
  $day1 = 0;#
  all days all years
  my $days_in_year;
  my $acumdays_per_month;
  my $daysinmonth;
  my $day;

  #
  full years + your day
  for my $y(1900. .3000) {
    my $leap_year = 0;#
    leap year
    my $leap_year_mask = 0;#
    leap year
    if ((($y % 4 == 0) && ($y % 100 != 0)) || ($y % 400 == 0) || ($y == 1900)) {
      $leap_year = 1;#
      leap year
      @cumul_d_in_m_selected = @cumul_d_in_m_leap;

    } else {
      $leap_year = 0;#
      leap year
      @cumul_d_in_m_selected = @cumul_d_in_m;
    }

    if (($day1 + (365 + $leap_year)) > $excelvalueintegerpart) {

      #
      found this year $y
      $year = $y;
      print "year $y\n";

      $days_in_year = $excelvalueintegerpart - $day1;
      $acumdays_per_month = 0;
      print "excelvalueintegerpart  $excelvalueintegerpart\n";
      print "day1  $day1\n";
      print "daysinyear $days_in_year\n";
      for my $i(0..$# cumul_d_in_m) {
        if ($i == $# cumul_d_in_m) {
          $month = $i + 1;#
          month 12 December
          $day = $days_in_year - $cumul_d_in_m_selected[$i];
          last;

        } else {

          if (($days_in_year > ($cumul_d_in_m_selected[$i])) && ($days_in_year <= ($cumul_d_in_m_selected[$i + 1]))) {
            $month = $i + 1;
            $day = $days_in_year - $cumul_d_in_m_selected[$i];
            last;
          }

        }

      }#
      end
      for $i months

      # end year
      last;

    } else {#
      full years
      $day1 += (365 + $leap_year);
    }

  }#
  end
  for years interger part comparator

  my $total_seconds_inaday;
  $total_seconds_inaday = "0\.$excelvaluedecimalpart" * 86400;

  $sec = $total_seconds_inaday;
  $hour = int($sec / (60 * 60));
  $sec -= $hour * (60 * 60);
  $min = int($sec / 60);
  $sec -= $min * (60);
  $sec = int($sec);
  return ($day, $month, $year, $hour, $min, $sec);

}
my $excelvariable = date2excelvalue(1, 3, 2018, 14, 14, 30);
print "Excel variable: $excelvariable\n";
my($integerpart, $decimalwithoutzero) = ($1, $2) if ($excelvariable = ~m / (\d + )\.(\d + ) / );
my($day1, $month, $year, $hour, $min, $sec) = excelvalue2date($integerpart, $decimalwithoutzero);
print "Excel Date from value: $day1, $month, $year, $hour, $min, $sec\n";
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

The problematic line was

```
$cellcon = $cell->unformatted();
```

Unless someone can offer a better explanation, I'll regard this as a bug. The line that I substituted was

```
$cellcon = $cell->Value;
```

Comment: I still have no idea about the first part of my question (why Excel provided the wrong integer for the number of days since Jan 1, 1900), but don't much care at this point. If someone can answer it, I will accept their answer instead of mine, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
use DateTime::Format::Excel;

my $datetime = DateTime::Format::Excel->parse_datetime( $cell->value() );
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.