# Reading Time format data in spreadsheet using perl

Tags: perl

while reading the spreadsheet using perl, how the time format data (in a cell) in spreadsheet got read by perl ?

I tried to read text and numeric type data from a cell in worksheet, as a result, it got read as text and numeric in perl, 
but while reading a time format data, it got converted to some float value(of format - `HH:MM:SS/HH:MM/MM:SS`), my doubt is that, how the time format (`[H]:MM:SS`) from a cell got read by perl ?

For example:
$cell holds the value of 13:7(is in time format `[H]:MM:SS` format in spreadsheet)

while reading it using perl,

`$type = $cell->type()` //returns the type : Numeric/Text

`$format = $cell->get_format()` // returns the format (i.e)if Numeric :returns time format of `HH:MM:SS / HH:MM / MM:SS` formats only

In such case, how data present in `$cell` can be read by perl? and how
other time formats such as `MM:SS.0/[H]:MM:SS/YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS/ [HH]:MM:SS...`are identified?

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable script that illustrates the problem you have

Comment: See also [reading dates from xls to csv through Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26934786/2173773), and according to [this thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1140328) you could try use `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` instead of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`

Comment: thanks for your Reply, but the even though i used `$cell->unformatted()` method / `$cell->Value` : both are acting the same way as `$cell-> {Val}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases (maybe all, but I've learned to be wary of statements like that), dates in Excel spreadsheets are stored as floating-point numbers where the integer part of the number is the number of days since the start of 1900 and the decimal part is how far through the day we are.

You can, of course, use that information to parse the data yourself. But there's no need to do that in a world where [DateTime::Format::Excel](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Excel) exists.